# Python and GPIOzero Motor function

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function, where I can pass a direction argument into the function to tell it to drive the motor either forward or backward.  The following is my test code:

```
from gpiozero import Motor
from time import sleep
motor=Motor(7,8)

def move(direction):
    print(direction)
    motor.direction()
    sleep(3)
    motor.stop()
    
move('forward')
```

The call passes the required direction, forward, to the function.  The print command in the function prints 'forward' to prove to myself that the direction is correctly received.  However it is not used by the motor control line as a parameter and just returns a load of errors.  If I replace `direction` after `motor` with `forward`, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just replace a function call by a string.

The simplest solution would be to use an `if`/`else` statement inside the `move` function.

```
if direction == 'forward':
    motor.forward()
elif direction == 'backward':
    motor.backward()  # or whatever is appropriate
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I thought it would be something like this but just couldn't solve it myself.  Works great now!